# Heroku Node.js - Web process failed to bind to $PORT

Tags: node.js, heroku

Deploying a node.js app on Heroku. Facing the below error.
`Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web
process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`
I don't have the PROC file in my app. The node.js app has started successfully. My code correctly uses process.env.PORT to bind.

`2016-10-14T15:34:52.802582+00:00 app[web.1]: Rest service ready on port 22712
2016-10-14T15:34:52.983831+00:00 app[web.1]: Subscription result:  {"success":true}
2016-10-14T15:34:52.864941+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2016-10-14T15:34:54.289684+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-10-14T15:30:03.693688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web
process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch`

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: added .Procfile still seeing the same error `2016-10-14T18:23:33.586722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web
process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2016-10-14T18:23:33.586722+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2016-10-14T18:23:33.715798+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2016-10-14T18:23:33.726733+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed`

Comment: How is your procfile? And how are you using the process.env.port?

Comment: Found the issue. I am using restify and creating server by specifying port and ip. the code was ported from openshift. For IP on openshift `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '127.0.0.1'` . Changed this to `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || '0.0.0.0';` to resolve the issue. Is there anything in heroku similar to `OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP`. May be i should set a config var as `"HEROKU_IP" to '0.0.0.0'` and change the code to  `process.env.OPENSHIFT_NODEJS_IP || process.env.HEROKU_IP||'127.0.0.1'`

Comment: added a config variable HEROKU_IP as '0.0.0.0' and changed code accordingly. Works fine.